# how to count unique values with some condition in dplyr in r

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
 ship_no     equip_name     yard      
  ABC          501           4A
  ABC          501           4A
  ABC          501           4D
  ABC          501           4D
  ABC          501           4B
  ABC          501           5B
  ABC          501           5C
  ABC          501           5E
  DEF          502           4D
  DEF          502           4D
  DEF          502           4C
  DEF          502           5C
  DEF          502           4L
  DEF          502           4L
  DEF          502           4L
  DEF          502           4G
```

I want to find how many times `equip_name` have crossed the `yard`.

Now,what I want to do is if `equip_name` has changed the yard from `4A to 5A or 4B to 5B, 4C to 5C till 4M to 5M and vice-versa` then it will be `horizontal crossover` else `vertical crossover`

My desired dataframe would be

```
  ship_no     equip_name     yard      Crossovers
  ABC          501           4A
  ABC          501           4A
  ABC          501           4D         Vertical
  ABC          501           4D
  ABC          501           4B         Vertical 
  ABC          501           5B         Horizontal
  ABC          501           5C         Vertical
  ABC          501           5E         Vertical  
  DEF          502           4D         Vertical
  DEF          502           4D
  DEF          502           4C         Vertical
  DEF          502           5C         Horizontal
  DEF          502           4L         Vertical
  DEF          502           4G         Vertical
```

Comment: You're not counting anything in your desired output, what do you want to count ? also it'd help to have horizontal crossover and vertical crossover in your output

Comment: Please check you expected outcome. I think the first `Vertical` for `502` is wrong, right? Either you want it grouped by the player, then there should be nothing or not. But then it should be `Horizontal`. Because `5B` to `4D`.

Comment: Your input data is not similar to your output dataframe. In addition, why is this row ` DEF          502           4D` assigned to `Vertical`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  extract(yard, into = c("a","b"),'(\\d+)(\\D+)', remove = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(equip_name) %>% 
  mutate(res=ifelse(a == lag(a), ifelse(b == lag(b), NA, "Vertical"),"Horizontal"))
Source: local data frame [10 x 6]
Groups: equip_name [2]

# A tibble: 10 x 6
   ship_no equip_name   yard     a     b        res
    <fctr>      <int> <fctr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>
 1     ABC        501     4A     4     A       <NA>
 2     ABC        501     4A     4     A       <NA>
 3     ABC        501     4D     4     D   Vertical
 4     ABC        501     4D     4     D       <NA>
 5     ABC        501     4B     4     B   Vertical
 6     ABC        501     5B     5     B Horizontal
 7     DEF        502     4D     4     D       <NA>
 8     DEF        502     4D     4     D       <NA>
 9     DEF        502     4C     4     C   Vertical
10     DEF        502     5C     5     C Horizontal
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But its giving `4C to 4E as Horizontal but actually a Vertical`

Comment: `4L to 4G`is also giving as `Horizontal` but, actually its `Vertical`

Comment: Sorry I can't help you as you are probably talking from data which is not included in your example data. Try to skip the `group_by(equip_name)` argument!?